# Using Nested Query Results in Lightning Input component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, lightning, community

I am trying to access the value of a child object from an embedded query in a given lightning component. I am unable to assign the "checked" attribute to the checkbox component based on the nested query result. Is this just not possible in Lightning or am I missing something? I am pretty new to salesforce, but I haven't come across any post that deals with such a situation.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.NestedQueryResultList}" var ="item">
                        <lightning:input type ="checkbox" label ="{!item.Name}" name="{!item.Id}" checked="{!item.ObjectA_ObjectB__r.SomeBooleanValue__c}" onchange="{!c.handleChange}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
```

The variable of interest here is -

> {!item.ObjectA_ObjectB__r.SomeBooleanValue__c}

I am loading the NestedQueryResult object from the doInit() initializer based on the Nested Soql Query, as below -

```
SELECT Id, Name,
            (SELECT id,SomeBooleanValue__c
             FROM ObjectA_ObjectB__r WHERE ObjectA__c = :givenId) 
FROM ObjectB__c
```

The Relationship between the objects is as follows -

> (Master)Object_A ----> (Child)ObjectA_ObjectB
>
> (Master)Object_B ----> (Child)ObjectA_ObjectB

Basically ObjectA_ObjectB is a link between ObjectA and ObjectB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the children. This means you'll have a nested iteration.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.NestedQueryResultList}" var ="item">
  <aura:iteration items="{!item.ObjectA_ObjectB__r}" var="child">
    <lightning:input type ="checkbox" label ="{!child.Name}" name="{!child.Id}" checked="{!child.SomeBooleanValue__c}" onchange="{!c.handleChange}"/>
  </aura:iteration> 
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The issue is I need the name from the Master, not the child. Is it possible to access the "item" variable in the nested iteration?

Comment: @A.WaliJr. Yes, you can still reference "item" inside of the "child" iteration.

Comment: Your workaround works. However, I need to add the checkbox even if item.ObjectA_ObjectB__r is null . Doing as you suggested means I end up losing some checkboxes which need to be added there.

Comment: @A.WaliJr. you may need to reconsider your design, then. This isn't a "workaround", it's how nested objects work. A list needs to be iterated over, and a subquery is always a list.

Comment: Your answer definitely pointed me in the right direction. I really appreciate the help. Thanks.